# How do we add wait feature in aws ecs update-service cli command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

Is that possible can we add  "wait" feature in below cli command without running another command "`aws ecs wait services-stable`"

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster "$CI_AWS_ECS_CLUSTER" --service "$CI_AWS_ECS_SERVICE" \
            --task-definition "family:revision" --wait ?
```

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible to make the first command wait. You have to run the `aws ecs wait services-stable` command after, if you want to wait on your deployment to complete.